# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation in jQuery - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to save user details like first name, last name and etc.along with user's profile image via Ajax calls. But I am getting error like "**Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation**" in console.So I searched over the network, and they said to add **.value** and the error is resolved. But now the form details are not submitted. Can any one help me to resolve this problem . Thanks in advance.

**HTML Form :**

```
<form id="userRegisterform"  name="userRegisterform" method="post">
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname"  name="firstname" placeholder="Enter First Name" required="true">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname"  name="lastname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" required="true">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">UserName</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1"  name="name1" placeholder="Enter UserName" required="true">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2"  name="email1" placeholder="Enter email" required="true">
        <small class="text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1"  name="password1" placeholder="Password" required="true">
    </fieldset>
    <div class = "form-group">
        <label><?php __('Select Files:', 'cvf-upload'); ?></label>
        <input type="file" name="file[0]" id="file" class="profileImage" required ="true" accept="image/*" >
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Submit" id="userRegister"/>
</form>
```

**jQuery Ajax Code:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#userRegisterform").validate({
        rules: {
            name1: {
                required: true
            },
            email1: "required",
            password1 : "required"
        },
        messages: {
            name1: {
                required: "Please provide your user name"
            },
            email1: "Please provide your email",
            password1 : "Please enter password"
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            var ajaxData = new FormData();
            $.each($(':input', form), function (i, fileds) { // appending all the form data
                ajaxData.append($(fileds).attr('name'), $(fileds).val());
            });
            ajaxData.append('action', 'athleteRegister');
            $.each($("input[type=file]"), function (i, obj) { // appending all the file uploads data
                $.each(obj.files, function (j, file) {
                    ajaxData.append('file[' + i + ']', file);
                })
            });

            console.log(ajaxData);
            var url = "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";
            var data = {
                formData1:ajaxData.value,
                action:'userRegistersave'
            };
            processData:false,
            $.post(url,data,function(response){
                  alert(response);
            });

            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

**My functions.php**

```
function userRegistersave() {
    if (isset($_REQUEST)) {
        print_r($_REQUEST);exit();
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: @cale_b. actually , I identified the reason behind the error and resolved. But i could't submit my form data. this is my question.

Comment: Well, I would argue you have not resolved it, and it would be useful to know the original issue.  IF you insist that's not the problem, then you should remove that information from the question, as it is just "noise" then.

Comment: Also - please make a clear problem statement.  "I cannot submit the form" is not useful.  Why not? What happens? Or doesn't happen?  Is there an error in the console? If so, what is it?  Does your `console.log(ajaxData)` run? Does it output data?

Comment: Your validate identifiers (email1, name1, etc) do not match any form elements.  You may want to fix that....